# sorting problem with datatables and jsonresult

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm using datables (datatables.net) in combination with sAjaxSource

like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


            $('#userTable').dataTable({
                "sAjaxSource": '<%= Url.Action("GetUserData", "Home") %>',
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bStateSave": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "aoColumns":
             [
                { "bSortable": false },
                null,
                { "sType": "title-string" },
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
             ]
            });
        });
```

the server method for this is like this

```
public JsonResult GetUserData()
{
   IList<string[]> userList = GetUserList();
   var sendData = new{aaData = userList};
   return new JsonResult {JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, Data = sendData};
}
```

everything works fine here, I can see the data in the table.
but, some of my properties of the user include some links to pictures 
for example

```
  userData[0] = string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='{1}' title='{1}' />", picUrl, title);
```

but in the table itself there is always the "/" missing. so the sorting over these columuns don't work. if i do a

```
 userData[0] =  string.Format("<img src='{0}'></img>", imgUrl);
```

the endtag is missing... in the tablecell the value is always

```
<img src='url' title='abc'>
```

so its either '/' missing or the whole endtag of img.

the start of the  json result:

```
{"aaData":[["\u003cimg src=\u0027/Content/image.png\u0027 class=\u0027profilePicture\u0027 /\u003e", ...[other elements]
```

did anybody else had this problem?

edit: i've just noticed it also converts ' to "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the solution..

the problem of not sorting was not the missing / or  instead i just changed

```
userdata[0] = string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='{1}' title='{1}' />", picUrl, title);
```

to

```
userdata[0] = string.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='{1}' title=\"{1}\" />", picUrl, title);
```

and than it worked :-)

i don't know why but it does :-)

thanks @cdeszaq for your support

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, for the image columns, [define your own sort method](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting) and [override what datatables is doing natively](http://datatables.net/development/sorting). That way you can ignore the images, or do whatever you want with them.

Comment: hmm yes thats true, but the strange thing is that either datatables or something else is changing the string which i am returning...

Comment: @nWorx - I would inspect the JSON that is getting returned from the server to see if that's the culprit. If not, it's somewhere higher up in the tree. I have noticed, however, that the Chrome inspector doesn't show the closing `/>` on image tags, so that could be another possible thing that's going on.

Comment: i've checked it also with firefox (firebug plugin) the / or the </img> tag is missing... i've added some <span></span> and the span tag is working... i will edit my initial post and add some json result..